# Typescript function overload type inference with deconstructed rest parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Given the following overloaded function:

```js
foo(tool: 'a', poaram: boolean, poarama: number): boolean
foo(tool: 'b', paramo: string, paramoa: string): boolean
foo(tool: 'a' | 'b', ...args: any[]): boolean {
    if (tool === 'a') {
        const [ poaram, poarama ] = args

    }

    return false
}
```

Is there any way to have `poaram` and `poarama` not be typed as `any` but as `boolean` and `number` respectively?

I am aware of [Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897), but I fail to see the connection to my use case above.

Comment: You need to make them all part of rest arguments. See example https://tsplay.dev/w14nyW . Let me know if it works for you. You don't even need to overload your function in this case. Please also keep in mind that it works only with TS nightly, 4.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are allowed to  use TypeScript nightly (4.6) you can consider this solution:

```js
function foo(...args: ['a', boolean, number] | ['b', string, string]): boolean {
    const [fst, scd, thrd] = args;
    if (fst === 'a') {
        const x = scd; // boolean
        const y = thrd // number

    }

    return false
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w14nyW)
Or even without rest parameters:

```js
function foo([first, second, third]: ['a', boolean, number] | ['b', string, string]): boolean {
    if (first === 'a') {
        const x = second; // boolean
        const y = third // number

    }

    return false
}
```

Above feature was added here [TypeScript/pull/46266](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/46266)

If you are not allowed, you should avoid tuple destructure:

```js
function foo(...args: ['a', boolean, number] | ['b', string, string]): boolean {
    if (args[0] === 'a') {
        const x = args[1]; // boolean
        const y = args[2] // number

    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: To assign the first argument to `tool`, `foo([tool, ...args]: ['a', boolean, number] | ['b', string, string]): boolean` should work too, right?

Comment: @DustInCompetent it looks like it does not work that way. I' can't say that I'm very familiar with this new feature, hence I'm unable to provide you with thorough explanation. Just did not have a chance to dig into it. It is not even released yet

Answer (score 0):

You could pick one of these for your function's implementation type:

```
foo(tool: 'a'|'b', ...args: [boolean, number]|[string, string]): boolean { // or
foo(tool: 'a'|'b', arg1: boolean|string, arg2: number|string): boolean {
```

Comment: That's true. But I was looking for a way without explicitly writing out the type of `...args` :)