# How can I get specific type inference in condition sentence in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```
interface Type {
  'number':number;
  'string':string;
}

function defineType<T extends keyof Type>(key:T,value:Type[T]) {
  if(key==='string') {
    // I expect the value inferred as Type['string'] but it not work
    // the sentence below report error
    // the type of value is still number | string
    const _value=value.split('.')
  }
}
```

[example link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOKDeAoZZAchAFcBbAI2iIC4yroBuA4gZzClAHM6OuQ3FgF88eGKRAIwwAPYhkAEwgxQEDNgA8qZBAAekEIrbIA1hHSyYaLBAA0APgAU59LVR2AbnAA2pCO62ANqoALoAlMj4hMAwLhYAvElE-DxEkdGEyAjyHMgA+t5+EAlF-gB0bJg+wGBOROXprKKiQA)

will the infer method help get the correct type?

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to use generics here. Just make illegal state unpresentable.

```js
interface Type {
  'number': number;
  'string': string;
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Params = {
  [Prop in keyof Type]: [key: Prop, value: Type[Prop]]
}

type Result = Values<Params>

function defineType([key, value]: Values<Params>) {
  if (key === 'string') {
    const _value = value.split('.') // string[]
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WvY94m)

`Params` - creates a hashmap data structure, where keys is a `Type` key and value is a tuple with two elements `[key: Prop, value: Type[Prop]]`

`Values` - obtains a union of all hashmap values.

So `Values<Params>` is just a union of allowed arguments `["string", string] | ["number", number]`.

Please keep in mind, that it works only in TS 4.6 `nightly version`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70109864/typescript-function-overload-type-inference-with-deconstructed-rest-parameter/70109998#70109998) might be even a duplicate. Let me know if my previous answer is helpful for your case. If it is, I will mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: amazing! thanks for your answer, it really helps

Comment: it seems the problem we encounter are pretty close,  it's reasonable to mark this as a duplicate.